# Design in Android, Shapes

Tags: android, xml, shapes

I wounder how its possible to make a shape like the example, with round corners and padding from the screen borders, and also put text inside, how is this possible?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use image buttons that contain image background with e.g. rounded corners or draw your own shapes, [Android Shapes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch).

Using [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) you can define hover, focus and default state of a button and appy a background image to each state.

Here is a small code example with source, [tutorial](http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/30/android-tutorial-image-text-only-buttons/).

Comment: I woudner how it possible to make padding so it dosen't get close nearby the screen-endings

Comment: go through this, you can apply paddings to layout elements http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html, http://www.androidpeople.com/android-layout-padding/

Comment: @Troj you don't want to deal with padding, adding margins will push the edge of the View away from the edge of the Activity.